# How to declare a array , then assign it later?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, initialization

```
class M{
    string s[5];
    M(){
        s = ["abc","abc","abc","abc","abc"]; // error, how i solve it?
    }
};
```

I want to declare a array as a private variable, then assign a value to it.

Answer (score 4):

Either you can use the mem-initializer list. For example

```
class M
{
    string s[5];
pyblic:
    M() : s{ "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc" }
    {
    }
};
```

Or instead of the array you could use standard class `std::array`. For example

```
#include <array>

class M
{
    std::<string, 5> s;
pyblic:
    M() 
    {
         s = { "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc" };
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are not assignable. But you can use the constructor initialization list:

```
M() : s{"abc","abc","abc","abc","abc"}
{
}
```

You can also initialize the member at the point of declaration:

```
class M{
    string s[5]= {"abc","abc","abc","abc","abc"};
    M(){}
};
```

Both of these require  C++11 compiler.

Alternatively, you can modify the array to contain the values you want. For example,

```
#include <algorithm> // for std::fill

M()
{
  std::fill(s, s+5, "abc");
}
```

Comment: If I use vs2010 which don't support C++11, how to accomplish it?

Comment: If the elements in the array were different from each other,eg {"a","b","c","d","e"}
how to accomplish it in a simple way without c++11 supported?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `vector` instead:

```
std::vector<string> s;
s = {"abc","abc","abc","abc","abc"};
```

Comment: `#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
class M {
    vector<string> s;
    public:
    M(){
        s = {"abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc"};
    }
};

int main(){
    return 0;
}`I use vs2010 to compile it ,but can't be successfully compiled.